# how append (key,value) with loop on python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, append

I want to create a new dict with a loop but I don't find the way to push key and value in loop with append. I try something like this but I'm still searching the good way.

```
frigo = {"mangue" : 2, "orange" : 8, "cassoulet" : 1, "thon" : 2, "coca" : 8, "fenouil" : 1, "lait" : 3}
new_frigo  = {} 

for i, (key, value) in enumerate(frigo.items()):
    print(i, key, value)
    new_frigo[i].append{key,value}
```

Comment: You don't call functions with `{  }` in Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's already a python function for that:

```
new_frigo.update(frigo)
```

No need for a loop! `dict.update(other_dict)` just goes and adds all content of the `other_dict` to the `dict`.

Anyway, if you *wanted* for some reason to do it with a loop,

```py
for key, value in frigo.items():
  new_frigo[key] = value
```

would do that. Using an `i` here makes no sense - a dictionary `new_frigo` doesn't have indices, but keys.

Comment: OP is adding index at new dictionary not key, need  explaination from him

Comment: @sahasrara62 they however state what they want to do in their text, and that is to add key/value pairs to `new_frigo`.

Comment: I am not good with english, just this is what his code is doing and ur code  is doing different then what he indend to do there

Comment: sorry, you must be misunderstanding something. He says: "i want to create new dict with a loop but i dont find the way to push key and value in loop with append". That's what he wants to do, make a new directory with a loop from keys and values he already has. So, my answer addresses exactly that.

Comment: if that is the case then this solve the problem, OP has added append in his statement and want to use that, so i posted this comment

Comment: yes i want push key,value in new_frigo ! dict already created i just need to fill new_frigo with loop thx marcus i will try with update

Comment: @FlorentV did it work out? If not, please leave a comment. If it did, I'd recommend you accept an answer ;)

Comment: yes its working thank you marcus :p

Comment: if your question is answered, please select the answer that solved it and click on the "checkmark" icon next to it, in order to mark the question as answered.

Comment: i cant vote :/ the site displaying me ( Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded. )

Comment: also i cant ask a new question on site i guess my first question have too many thumbs down

Answer (score -1):

You can use `update` to append the key and values in the dictionary as follows:

```
frigo = {"mangue": 2, "orange": 8, "cassoulet": 1, "thon": 2, "coca": 8, "fenouil": 1, "lait": 3}
new_frigo = {}

for (key, value) in frigo.items():
    new_frigo.update({key:value})

print(new_frigo)
```

Result:

```
{'mangue': 2, 'orange': 8, 'cassoulet': 1, 'thon': 2, 'coca': 8, 'fenouil': 1, 'lait': 3}
```

Comment: Please use the code formatting button over the answer editor to make your code appear correctly! Also, explaining what this does would make your answer better.

Comment: please do not post screenshots of text. Instead, as said, use the code formatting button.

Comment: I am new here, Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: You are not using `i` at all, so why use `enumerate`? And `new_frigo.update({key:value})` is written much more idiomatically as `new_frigo[key] = value`...

Comment: I didn't noticed that, I just edited his code as he wanted.